# PHP Multidimensional Arrray

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Im having problems trying to figure out a way in which i can solve the following, where if the elements of the arrays are common to one another they merge to form a new array with each other.

For instance, if I have:

```
$array = [ [0,4], [1,2], [1,3], [3,2] ]
```

Then the new array would be like:

```
$newarray = [ [0,4], [1,2,3] ]
```

Where the arrays of `$array` which have elements in common then merge, I've tried a couple of ways like looping through the array and comparing individual elements but just can't get my head around it, any help would be great

Another simple example would be:

```
$array2 = [ [0,1], [3,4], [4,2], [2,3], [6,5] ];

$newarray2 = [ [0,1], [2,3,4], [5,6]]
```

thanks

Comment: look into [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) and [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$array2 = [ [0,1], [3,4], [4,2], [2,3], [6,5] ];
$wrk = array_count_values(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array2));
ksort($wrk);
$result = [];
$prevValue = -INF;
$i = -1;
foreach($wrk as $key => $value) {
    if ($value != $prevValue) {
        $prevValue = $value;
        ++$i; 
    }
    $result[$i][] = $key;
}
var_dump($result);
```